# How can I force the opening of my jQuery Dialog even if I've a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently working on a jQuery Dialog and I've a problem. Here's my JavaScript code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.overlay-trigger').click(function()
    {
        $('#expose-mask').fadeIn(function()
        {
            $('.overlay-box').css({'display':'block'});
        });
    });
    $('.overlay-box-closer, #expose-mask').click(function()
    {
        $('.overlay-box, #expose-mask').css({'display':'none'});
    });
});
```

my HTML code:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a id="help" class="overlay-trigger" href="help.php">Help</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <span id="footer-copyright">
            <a href="./..">Coded by Dylan.</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="overlay-box">
    <div class="overlay-box-container">
        <span class="overlay-box-closer" title="Close the overlay"></span>
        <h1 class="big-title">Help</h1>
        <p>Your privacy is important to us. To better protect your privacy we provide this notice explaining our online information practices and the choices you can make about the way your information is collected and used. To make this notice easy to find, we make it available in our footer and at every point where personally identifiable information may be requested.Log files are maintained and analysed of all requests for files on this website's web servers. Log files do not capture personal information but do capture the user's IP address, which is automatically recognised by our web servers.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="expose-mask" style="display: none;"></div>
```

and my CSS code:

```
.overlay-box
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 40%;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 7px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 7px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 7px;
}

.overlay-box-container
{
    margin: 20px;
}

#expose-mask
{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

As you can see, in my link `<a id="help" class="overlay-trigger" href="help.php">Help</a>` I've my href and my class `overlay-trigger`that performs the opening of the overlay. If I put # in my href, the overlay opens well: http://prntscr.com/686n07

I'd like to put a link to my "Help" text, but when I click the link, the overlay does not open and I'm directly redirected to the link. I'd like that even if there's a link, the overlay is opened anyway. Like this example: http://community.invisionpower.com/register/ (click the "Privacy Policy" text).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prevent the default behavior using [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/):

```
$('.overlay-trigger').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $('#expose-mask').fadeIn(function(){
        $('.overlay-box').css({'display':'block'});
    });
});
```